# Am I doing execution timing measurement in Go in a useful way?

Tags: go, timing

My code:

```
        // repeat fib(n) 10000 times
        i := 10000
        var total_time time.Duration
        for i > 0 {

            // do fib(n) -> f0
            start := time.Now()
            for n > 0 {
                f0, f1, n = f1, f0.Add(f0, f1), n-1
            }
            total_time = total_time + time.Since(start)

            i--
        }

        // and divide total execution time by 10000
        var normalized_time = total_time / 10000
        fmt.Println(normalized_time)
```

The execution times I'm seeing are so extremely short that I am suspicious that what I've done isn't useful. If it's wrong, what am I doing wrong and how can I make it right?

Comment: What is `n` initialized to?

Comment: https://progolang.com/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go/

Comment: An integer input from console by user.

Comment: Okay, that's not an ideal way to do benchmarks. Read the blog linked above for the proper approach.

Comment: Use the built-in benchmarking system in the `testing` package for benchmarks.